# How to select last and last but one records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns `id, type, value` like in image below.

[image: example]

What I'm trying to do is to make a query to get the data in this format:

```
type     previous  current
month-1  666       999
month-2  200       15
month-3  0         12
```

I made this query but it gets just the last value

```
select * 
  from statistics 
 where id in (select max(id) from statistics group by type)    
 order 
    by type
```

[image]

EDIT: Live example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af81da/1

Thanks!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
select s.*,
       (select s2.value
        from statistics s2
        where s2.type = s.type
        order by id desc
        limit 1, 1
       ) value_prev
from statistics s
where id in (select max(id) from statistics s group by type) order by type;
```

This should be relatively efficient with an index on `statistics(type, id)`.

Comment: This is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
type,
ifnull(max(case when seq = 2 then value end),0 ) previous,
max( case when seq = 1 then value end ) current
from
(
select *, (select count(*)
           from statistics s 
           where s.type = statistics.type
           and s.id >= statistics.id) seq
from statistics ) t
where seq <= 2
group by type
```

Comment: This seems like a very inefficient way to solve this problem . . . it works, it just seems inefficient.